# Woocommerce: how to make only certain products shippable?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm new to Woocommerce and am struggling to find a way to make only certain products shippable. I am creating an e-shop of physical products (food) and I want to configure that some of these products could be shipped and others could not (because some are too delicate). That is said, when the customer choose a non-shippable product he can pay it on the eshop and has to collect it in the store but can't get it delivered.

Is there is way to specify a certain property when creating a new product. Or do I need to download a pluggin? Which one could make the trick?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have used WooCommerce so my terminology may be a little off, but here it goes...

In WooCommerce you have the ability to create `shipping classes`, these when assigned to individual products will dictate the shipping options available for those products.

There are a number of plugins that further enhance the WooCommerce shipping system, but if you go to `WooCommerce > Settings` from your site's dashboard you will see a section for `shipping` and within that you can set-up your rules to charge certain fees, or disallow shipping altogether for products based from your shipping classes set against products.

Not sure whether that helps at all. Hopefully it points you in the right direction.